# PHP MySQL query two row columns between

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm having a hard time with this query logic.  I'm passing in an array with coordinates which create a box of visible area.  I'm trying to return any possible location within that box.  The array of coordinates looks like this:

```
$array['farLeftLat']=>value;
$array['farLeftLon']=>value;

$array['farRightLat']=>value;
$array['farRightLon']=>value;

$array['nearLeftLat']=>value;
$array['nearLeftLon']=>value;

$array['nearRightLat']=>value;
$array['nearRightLon']=>value;
```

In my database the row has two columns as latitude and longitude:

```
id  |  latitude  |  longitude  | .....
 1  |  value     |  value      | .....
 2  |  value     |  value      | .....
```

I need to group the database row instances of latitude and longitude together and check it for farLeft, farRight, nearLeft, nearRight...

```
"SELECT * FROM locations WHERE (//row instance of lat<farLeftLat and row instance of lon>farLeftLon)
AND (//row instance of lat<farRightLat and row instance of lon<farRightLon)..."
```

ANSWER:

After looking at the coordinates more closely, got a better understanding.  I just needed four coordinates: the top and bottom lines (latitudes) and left and right lines (longitudes).  So my query looks like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM locations WHERE (latitude BETWEEN $array['nearLeftLat'] 
AND $array['farLeftLat']) AND (longitude BETWEEN $array['farLeftLon'] AND $array['farRightLon'])"
//wrong syntax with 's but I declared variables in my code.
```

The trick here is that the smaller value has to come first...got stuck on that too.

Comment: In order to help you solve your question, I think I need more information: 1) What type of coordination system are you referencing to (Cartesian Coordinate System, Geographic Coordinate System,.. )? 2) The boxes you are referring to, are they always parallel to the axes? 'cause if they are not parallel to the axes, it is more complicated to determine whether a location is within the box, or not. 3) What do you mean with *near* and *far*, do you mean *top right corner*, *bottom left corner*, etc..? 4) I'm not sure whether I got your question right, so let me know if this is the wrong direction.

Comment: I actually figured out the answer...don't want to delete the question, against SO rules.  The coordinate system comes from iOS GoogleMaps, so the values are just decimals.  Near/Far are the corners.  I'll post the answer in my question.  Thanks for replying tho